# How to make cycle which works with pandas.DataFrame work faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to prepare data for analysis and run code like this:

```
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i,'col1'] = func1(df.loc[i,'colA_1'],y1,z)
    .....
    df.loc[i,'colN'] = funcN(df.loc[i,'colA_N'],yN,z)
```

But because of df's lenght (about 100000 records) and number of functions execution of this code takes up to 1 day. Does anyone has any idea how to make this stuff work faster?
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: buy a faster computer?

Comment: You did not give much code, so I can only advise to get a faster machine.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. Mine is pretty old but still it has 4 cores while cycle uses only one (?) I was thinking about stuff like 'Threading'. I tried dividing DataFrame into 4 parts and run them in different Threads, but for some reason it didn't worked. Maybe someone has good examples of using 'Threading' & DataFrames?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code a little cleaner and slightly more efficient by using [`DataFrame.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) instead.

```
df.transform({'col1': func1, ...})
```

But I would still expect it to take a long time. Most of the time in this code is *probably* taken up by your function, not by the indexing. So I'd suggest looking for ways to make your function faster.

Comment: I haven't dug deep into the `DataFrame.transform` code, but if it works anything like `apply`, it's not really vectorized, and is essentially a Python for-loop.

Comment: OK, I'll just avoid mentioning that then. In any case the only possible vectorization I had in mind would have been related to indexing.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but maybe there's a way to parallelise cycle somehow?

Comment: @iveagle What "cycle" are you talking about?

Comment: Oh, you mean to parallelize the loop? There's lots of information online about how to do that, including many questions on this site. Have a look around for "pandas multiprocessing" or similar.